My Ivy with sticky shiny substance on leaves
My Ivy has aphids and a silver sticky substance on the leaves. The sticky falls to my floor and is sticky on the floor.
What can I do?

You need to get rid off the aphids.
The sticky substance is called honeydew and is secreted by the aphids when they suck the plant sap and it contains sugars, which is why it’s sticky.
The reasons why you should get rifbodbthe aphids are mainly two:

If there is an excessive number of them, they will weaken the plant - and if honeydew collects under the plant, that’s an indicator of “too many”.
The nutrient-rich honeydew can lead to fungal growth and then you are dealing with two issues instead of one.

There are many methods to get rid of the aphids, from insecticides to washing them off repeatedly, check this site for suggestions. One caveat: Of you observe ants around the aphids, they are farming them for the honeydew. In that case, beneficial insects are not an option and you need to be careful, because the ants will sometimes bring new aphids once you have removed the first ones.
